# Creating a generic base

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, refactoring

I'm trying to pull my genric functionalities to a base class, however the diverse data type is stopping me from doing this. Please see:

```
public class OutWriter
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<long> series1;
        private readonly IEnumerable<long> series2
        private readonly IEnumerable<long> series3
        private readonly IEnumerable<double> series4
        private readonly double sum;

public OutWriter()
{
  series1 = PopulateS1()
  series2 = PopulateS2()
  series3 = PopulateS3()
  series4 = PopulateS4()

sum = series4.Aggregate((x,y)=>x+y);
}
}

public class PaperWriter
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<BigInteger> series1;
        private readonly IEnumerable<BigInteger> series2
        private readonly IEnumerable<BigInteger> series3
        private readonly IEnumerable<BigInteger> series4
        private readonly BigInteger sum;

public PaperWriter()
{
  series1 = PopulateS1()
  series2 = PopulateS2()
  series3 = PopulateS3()
  series4 = PopulateS4()

sum = series4.Aggregate((x,y)=>x+y);
}
}

public class Base<T>()
{
    ????
}
```

I'm trying to pull up the similarities, however there is `long`, `double` and `BigInteger` involved.  Also the aggregate throws out a compile time error due to the + operation. Can you please tell me how to do it appropriately?

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Ain't that easy with these types I'm afraid as there is no generic constraint that can be used for those operators.  However, this question comes up all the time and I believe Jon Skeet (could be someone else, don't recall) had a pretty good solution.  It's on SO somewhere, but I can't search for it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in C# that unifies mathematical rings. There are workarounds, such as the [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/index.html) package maintained by the infamous Jon Skeet, and the Operator utility written by another StackOverflow freqenter Marc Gravel, and description of its use can be found [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html). The idea is to extract the addition, multiplication et al operations as function calls. The link provides an `Operator` class that uses expressions to provide addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, less than, equality and other operators... and it's all easily extensible.